# Non-nullable instance field '_dio' must be initialized Flutter

Tags: flutter, dio

I am using Dio for Json parsing and i have created a class for simple Json parsing and serializing but i am getting the following error

```
Non-nullable instance field '_dio' must be initialized. (Documentation)  Try adding an initializer expression, or add a field initializer in this constructor, or mark it 'late'.
```

Below is the code for my class

```
Dio _dio;

  final baseUrl = "";

  HttpService(){
    _dio = Dio(BaseOptions(
      baseUrl:
    ));
  }
```

What might i be doing wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your variable `_dio` is non-nullable which means it can never be null.
However when you put `Dio _dio;` it doesn't get a value.

You have 2 options:

Either make it nullable by putting a `?` after the type: `Dio? _dio;`

or make it a `late` variable `late Dio _dio;` which means that it will shortly after get a value (hopefully `_dio = Dio(BaseOptions(baseUrl:));` will do so) so that it can be treated as "never null" afterwards.

**EDIT:**
More on that topic: https://dart.dev/null-safety